# Is it feasible to merge Mongoengine into Django tree as a database backend from architectural point of view?

Tags: django, mongoengine

I love Django and would generally prefer it to micro-frameworks so that I don't re-invent bicycles, but rather use batteries included. I mostly rely on Django REST Framework for creation of REST APIs and don't really use round-trip part of Django (e.g. Templates and Forms).

But I desperately need MongoDB support for my projects. In many fields, such as bioinformatics, you have to use deeply nested JSONs. There are 2 ways to deal with this in pure Django:

1. Represent nested JSON data as Relational tables, which is a huge waste of time.
2. Use JSONField for nested JSON data - a crutch, because you often need to specify schema for those JSONs (which you have to do on application level) or use hyperlinks or other complex fields in those JSON data (which is impossible).

There'a quite popular library, mongoengine, which strictly follows Django ORM API. I feel like it was meant to be a part of Django. But to use it with Django so far, you have to re-implement every single bit of integration by yourself (authentication, management commands, Django REST Framework integration etc.).

So, I thought: what's the problem? Why can't we integrate Mongoengine into Django once and for all as another database backend? Django already has Postgres-specific fields. Why can't we just have Mongo-specific? The only obstacle I can see is architectural design of Django, which might have strong assumptions about SQL-ish database nature and be incompatible with Mongo.

If you're good at Django architecture, can you share your considerations about feasibility of this integration attempt?

Comment: "Why can't we integrate Mongoengine into Django once and for all as another database backend?" Because JavaScript on the server was meant to make life easy, and there are no easy ways to the right things - Django is based on Python's ecosystem while Mongo is JavaScript. JavaScript is not a domain specific language and not a magic bullet. You need performance and JSON? You have Go and custom modules to provide JSON solutions.

Comment: @dmitryro Mongo is not about javascript in the first place. It is more about nested data structures. Sometimes you just don't need relations, you need to bind nested data to its parent forever. Sometimes you need relations. Mongoengine supports relations at application level. So it works as a superset of RDBMS. May be much slower in some cases, but still worth considering.

Comment: You have JSON support and document data types in Postgres as well. Your problem is a problem, but it's not fundamental enough for the major paradigm shift in framework philosophy.

Comment: The problem will be solved when there will be low-level language (C or C++) implementation for JSON-data - like Redis is coded in C for a good reason - to perform, to scale, to manage memory the right way.

Comment: @dmitryro Unfortunately, representing a huge sub-document as just JSONField is not fine-grained enough, as you need schema for it. JSONField needs to allow for recursive models on Django level, but that's not available, unfortunately. Sorry, I don't see connection with C/C++ level. It seems that if Django allowed for sub-models within JSONField, that would've been enough.

Comment: For you to see it's needed to know how the apps are built, not how to use them only. And if they're not built with the right technology (and JavaScript was born in the browser not to build OS kernel), they will always have hidden issues - for the same reason Ruby is not integrated into Django, Mongo is not integrated into Django.

Comment: http://www.aptuz.com/blog/is-postgres-nosql-database-better-than-mongodb/

Comment: @dmitryro I don't suggest to build MongoDB codebase into Django. I suggest to build Mongoengine inside Django. Mongoengine is a python library, which provides Django-like interface for mongodb, built on top of PyMongo (python interface for mongodb, almost identical to mongo's javascript API).

Comment: It's not feasible as MongoDB uses different philosophy and has different echosystem. It's completely foreign to Python's echosystem by birth and will not be a part of it as common sense, architectural purity and consistency matter  and not convenience of a certain group of users.

Comment: Even a powerful tool like Django Rest Framework is not a part of core Django, as it only serves a limited audiences with special needs for REST and JSON. If there will be an enthusiasm and motivation in certain group to build similar integration for Mongo (which I doubt) - there will be an integration.  Django belongs to Python family, and its mentality and philosophy are fundamentally different from those in Ruby and JavaScript communities.

Comment: Just carefully read Zen of Python and try analyzing what exactly prevents MongoDB integration from being a part of Django.

Answer (score 1):

I personally found this method really helpful and straightforward. You may give it a try:

http://django-mongodb-engine.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/setup.html

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. Did you use it extensively? It seems long dead, judging from Github: https://github.com/django-nonrel/mongodb-engine/issues. Mongoengine is not doing great either, but it is definitely alive. So, I think, Mongoengine is much more feature-rich by now.

Comment: I did not use if for creating REST APIs but other than that I used in pretty extensively abd it works well for me! :)